# Typedoc throws error with a node_modules package.json

Tags: typedoc

I'm pretty new using Typedoc and I have troubles with a thrown error.

When I run Typedoc in my project, the doc is correctly generated but I also get an error:

`$ ./node_modules/.bin/typedoc --mode file --module commonjs --out ./docs/typescript --target es5 src/
Error: Could not parse /home/michael/workspace/test/node_modules/paralleljs/package.json`

I don't understand why Typedoc looks into node_modules/ while I specified to generate the docs on src/ (both are at the same level).

I also tried to exclude `node_modules` with `--exclude "**/node_modules/**/*"` or `--externalPattern "**/node_modules/**/*"` but it seems to do nothing.

If someone could help / explain me why it is behaving like that, i would be grateful to him/her.

Answer (score 0):

Typedoc will read type information from a project's dependencies, therefore it looks at the `node_modules` directory. The best way to avoid this would be to exclude the `node_modules` directory (see bug [#313](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/issues/319)).

TypeDoc also [looks at](https://github.com/TypeStrong/typedoc/blob/a2fab7cf1b5957c2e05ffd3882583dcf812ea8c7/src/lib/converter/plugins/PackagePlugin.ts#L128-L133) the current project's `package.json` file so that will need to be valid JSON as well.

*See also [gitter conversation](https://gitter.im/TypeStrong/typedoc?at=5bcd9895ae7be94016982144)*